# C++ text animation Error C2397

Tags: c++, visual-studio, youtube

I writted this code from a youtube video (from Husam Haj):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C2k-xiLmNSQ

This code is supposed to Animate Text (See the video) using C++, but the thing is that this code doesn't work since I got the following message from visual studio 2017:

**"error C2397: conversion from 'int' to 'SHORT' requires a narrowing conversion"**

I was researching in the internet and I found that someone already asked for help with this same code, but not solution:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/358635-i-need-some-help/

I would appreciate any help

Below is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Display(string[], const int);

int main()
{
const int arr_size = 12;
string myInfo[arr_size] = { " Animated text example",
  "     Brooklyn College",
  "  Pre-Engineering Program",
 };

 Display(myInfo, arr_size);

 return 0;
}

void Display(string arr_string[], int arr_size)
{
 HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

COORD pos[18] = { { 0,6 },{ 0,7 },{ 0,9 },{ 0,11 },{ 0,13 },{ 0,15 },
 { 0,17 },{ 0,19 },{ 0,21 },{ 0,23 },{ 0,25 },{ 0,27 },
 { 0,29 },{ 0,31 },{ 0,33 },{ 0,35 },{ 0,37 },{ 0,39 } };

 for (int k = 0; k<arr_size; k++)
{
  for (int j = arr_string[k].size(); j >= 0; j--)
{
   for (int i = 0; i <= j; i = i++)
{
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, pos[k]);
    cout << " " << endl;
    pos[k].X++;

    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, pos[k]);
    cout << arr_string[k][j] << endl;
    Sleep(1);
}
pos[k] = {0,k+1}; //HERE THE MISTAKE!
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The complaint is you have a 32 bit number being stuffed into a 16 bit space and may suffer data loss. Would have expected that to be a warning, not a compiler error.

I don't know of a suffix for forcing [an integer literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) to a 16 bit integer, so a quick and cheesy solution is to cast

```
pos[k] = {(SHORT)0,(SHORT)(k+1)};
```

You'll have a similar problem with

```
for (int j = arr_string[k].size(); j >= 0; j--)
```

because you're assigning the unsigned integer from `size()` to a signed integer.

```
for (size_t j = arr_string[k].size(); j >= 0; j--)
```

should solve that.  And while we are here, watch out for

```
for (int i = 0; i <= j; i = i++)
```

because you don't know if you get the increment (`i++`) or the assignment (`i=`) first.

Comment: _32 bit number being stuffed into a 16 bit_ ... that's true for the Windows platform but strictly spoken, an `int` is not required to be 32-bit and a `short` is not required to be 16-bit in size.

Comment: @zett42 Funny. Just finished making a comment about endianness and exactly the same thing in another question.

Comment: Additional note. Microsoft guarantees `SHORT` is 16 bit.

Comment: OK I'll give you that one.

Comment: @zett42 And I'll give you it's the math, not the string literal, that causes the problem, so it only needs one cast. Your answer's the more correct. I'm leaving mine because of the sequencing point gotcha at the end needs to be brought to light.

Comment: _sequencing point gotcha_ ... is this really an issue? The increment is a side effect of the expression so IMO it's guaranteed to be executed *after* the assignment. So the assignment would be just a noop.

Comment: @zett42 You may have a point there. The increment won't necessarily happen after the assignment, but it is questionable whether it matters or not if `i` is incremented then assigned or assigned then incremented. At least not with an `int`. It would matter with overloaded = or ++.

Answer (score 0):

`pos` is an array of `COORD`. When I press F12 (go to definition), it shows me:

```
typedef struct _COORD {
    SHORT X;
    SHORT Y;
} COORD, *PCOORD;
```

`SHORT` is just a typedef for `short`.

You assign `k + 1` which is of type `int` to `COORD::y` which is of type `short`. A variable of type `short` is *shorter* (having a smaller range of possible values) than `int` so the compiler rightfully complains.

To fix the error, either declare `short k` or use `static_cast` which does the "narrowing conversion" the compiler likes to have:

```
pos[k] = {0, static_cast<SHORT>(k+1)};
```

This only works correctly because console screen coordinates are in a sufficiently small range to fit into a `short`.

Comment: "sufficiently small range to fit into a short." Unless you are Weird Al Yankovic and have a flat screen monitor forty inches wide.

Comment: @user4581301 that must be a very high DPI 40 inches monitor that fits 32767 characters horizontally and you need very good eyes because a single character would be .03mm in width ;-)

Comment: He's mother <expletive deleted> Weird Al. Best white Rapper since the Beastie Boys. Jesus. That song's almost 20 years old. Can you imagine how big his monitor is today?